# Caching in binary search trees

Tags: caching, binary-search-tree, nodes, red-black-tree

I have a program where I input keys and the position value from the input list into a red-black tree. If a key occurs more than once in the input array, the key is not inserted again into the tree; instead, the position value is updated.

For example, for the input list S E A R C H T R E E, the first time E is encountered, it is input and its position value is stored as 1 (position value starts at 0); the second time E is encountered in the list, it is not added again to the tree; only its position value is updated to 8. The third time E is encountered, its position value is updated to 9.

Throughout the program, I want to keep track of the last node that has been accessed, so that if the next key in the input list is the same as the previous one, I can access in constant time the node containing that key and modify the position value without having to go through the tree and search for the node containing that key to modify the position value. It is like a form of caching.

Is this possible?

Input is done through put method. I store the key of the last input but I have no idea how I can directly access the node containing that key without having to search the tree. Searching the tree would require a loop, which would not result constant time for accessing the node.

```
public class RedBlackTree<Key extends Comparable, Value> {

    private static final boolean RED = true;
    private static final boolean BLACK = false;
    private Node root;
    private int N; //number of nodes in RBT
    private Key latestKey; //most recently input key

    private class Node{
        private Key key; //key (data stored in node)
        private Value val; //sequence order (whether the key was input first (0), second (1), third (2), etc)
        private Node left, right; //links to left and right subtrees
        private boolean colour; //colour of node
        private int N; //subtree count

        public Node (Key key, Value val, boolean colour, int N){
            this.key = key;
            this.val = val;
            this.colour = colour;
            this.N = N;
        }
    }

    //get sequence order of given key; start searching at root
    public Value get(Key key){
        return get(root, key);
    }

    //get position of given key; start searching at subtree rooted at x
    public Value get(Node x, Key key){
        int cmp;
        while (x != null){
            cmp = key.compareTo(x.key); //compare key being searched for with current key read
            if (cmp < 0){ //key being searched for is smaller than current key
                x = x.left; //go to left child of current key
            }else if (cmp > 0){ //key being searched for is larger than current key
                x = x.right; //go to right child of current key
            }else{ //key being searched for is equal to current key
                return x.val; //return sequence order
            }
        }
        return null; //given key not found
    }

    //insert key-value pair; start at root
    //if key already present, overwrite old value with new value
    //therefore, if a key occurs at several positions in input list, last position is the one saved
    public void put(Key key, Value val){
        if (latestKey != null && (latestKey.compareTo(key) == 0)){
            //how to find the node containing that key?
        }
        root = put(root, key, val);
        root.colour = BLACK;
        latestKey = key;
    }

    //insert key-value pair in subtree rooted at x
    public Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val){
        if (x == null){ //do standard insert, with red link to parent
            N = N + 1;
            return new Node(key, val, RED, 1);
        }
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key); //compare key to be inserted with current key read
        if (cmp < 0){ //key to be inserted is smaller than current key
            x.left = put(x.left, key, val); //recursive call to insert key-value pair in subtree rooted at current key's left child
        }else if (cmp > 0){ //key to be inserted is larger
            x.right = put(x.right, key, val); //recursive call to insert key-value pair in subtree rooted at current key's right child
        }else{ //key to be inserted is current key read
            x.val = val; //overwrite value (store last position up to now)
        }

        //fix any right-leaning links
        if (isRed(x.right) && !isRed(x.left)){ //right-leaning red link that needs to be rotated to lean to the left
            x = rotateLeft(x);
        }
        if (isRed(x.left) && isRed(x.left.left)){ //rotate right a node with two left-leaning red links
            x = rotateRight(x);
        }
        if (isRed(x.left) && isRed(x.right)){ //flips colours to pass a red link up the tree (when passing 4-node)
            flipcolours(x);
        }
        x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
        return x;
    }

    //other methods...
}
```

Comment: Of course it is possible to perform caching such as you describe.  Since `Node` objects hold a reference to their key, I'd suggest replacing `private Key latestKey` with `private Node latestNode`, with the appropriate corresponding changes.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `private Key latestKey` with `private Node latest` and made the following changes.

```
public void put(Key key, Value val){
    if ((latest != null) && (latest.key.compareTo(key) == 0)){
        latest.val = val;
        return;
    }
    root = put(root, key, val);
    root.colour = BLACK;
}

public Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val){
    if (x == null){
        N = N + 1;
        latest = new Node(key, val, RED, 1);
        return latest;
    }
    if (x != null){
        latest = x;
    }
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key); //compare key to be inserted with current key read
    //etc
}
```